# $.ajax call is appending some kind of extra query param

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm running an ASP.NET MVC site via IIS Express.

So for example I set up this test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var carServiceUrl = "http://localhost:43889/cars";

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $.ajaxSetup(
        {
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json"
            contentType: "application/json"
        });

    });

    get();

    function get()
    {
        var url = carServiceUrl;

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            async: true,
            url: carServiceUrl,
            dataType: "json",

            success: onGetCarsSuccess
        });
    }

 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is when I launch FireBug, and I load this page, the get() is getting fired but the request has some kind of appended value to it in the querystring (e.g. `http://localhost:43889/cars?_=1381820301163`) and I have no idea how it's getting there.  I don't know if it's because I'm running this in an MVC project or that I'm running all this via IIS Express or what.  I usually use straight IIS so not sure.

I'm not sure why it's even appending `?_=1381820301163` to the request.  I never specified that in my jQuery call.

Comment: It is a timestamp, but no idea why it appears

Answer (score 4):

From the jQuery ajax documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be
> cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work
> correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending
> "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for
> other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL
> that has already been requested by a GET.

Answer (score 3):

try remove `cache: false`

`It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters.`

see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/